# Fitsharp, how to give symbols as argument?

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm using FitNesse with FitSharp (.Net), and I'm trying to Setup a test suite :

1. Generate a random *port*
2. Setup execution *path*
3. Start process on *port*, in *path*, and retreive it's *pid*

My C# code looks like this:

```
public int RandomPort() {...}
public int SetupWebsite() {...}
public int StartWebsite(string path, int port) {...}
```

My Fitnesse looks like this:

```
!|Setup|
|RandomPort?|
|>>port|

!|Setup|
|SetupWebsite?|
|>>path|

!|Setup|
|StartWebsite?|<<path|<<port|
|>>pid|
```

The error : `fitSharp.Machine.Exception.MemberMissingException: Member 'startwebsite' with 0 parameter(s) not found for type 'Web.Api.Tests.Setup'.`

I've try many things, but it never works, the problem is not that i'm doing something wrong (wich is obvious), but I can't find how to do it right...

I'm really having a hard time with Fitnesse... I can't find anywhere and up-to-date tutorial, or any ressources to help me creating a nice SuiteTest... To add more context on my question, I want to start an IISExpress (my Setup) on a Web.Api 2 project, And then make some Json/Rest calls on it, my Teardown should simply kill the IISExpress process, and clear the tempory website folder.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol save operator (>>) and the symbol recall operator (<<) can be used to collect a value at one place in a story test and then use it in other places. The symbol save operator can be used in any expected value cell. Instead of comparing the actual value to an expected value, the actual value is saved with the symbol name.

You can use the `check` keyword:

```
!|setup|
|check|randomport|>>port|
|check|setupwebsite|>>path|
|check|startwebsite|<<path||<<port|>>pid|
```

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/SymbolValues.html

You can also use the `name` keyword. The `name` keyword assigns an object to a symbol name, which can be used to retrieve the object later.

```
!|setup|
|name|port|randomport|
|name|path|setupwebsite|
|name|pid|startwebsite|<<path||<<port|
```

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/NameKeyword.html

Note that in a method call, the method name is made by concatenating every other cell. The other alternating cells are input values.

Comment: With both methods, i get the error `fitSharp.Machine.Exception.MemberMissingException: Member 'startwebsiteport' with 1 parameter(s) not found for type 'fitlibrary.DoFixture`.

I don't understand why the method name `startwebsite` is concatenate with the `port` symbol ?

Comment: Oops! Corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike, it's almost done. I don't understand why, but i have to change the method `StartWebsite`, to be something like `StartWebsiteOnPortAndPath`, so I can split the call... Weird.

My final result :

```
!|setup|
|check|random port|>>port|
|check|setup website|>>path|
|check|start website on port|<<port|and path|<<path|>>pid|
```

Comment: It's a format invented by Rick Mugridge, the creator of FitLibrary. You can put empty cells in between the parameter cells if you want. See my corrected answer.  http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitLibraryUserGuide.DoFixture